# changing to a different SVN repository for a project in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, svn, xcode4

I have a project which I regularly commit to an SVN repository named "repo1", for some reason, I needed to change the project's repository location to "repo2" so any future commits/updates will take place to "repo2". Is that possible in XCode 4? if yes, how ?

p.s. I have SVN server on the local network which has two repos: repo1 & repo2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would use svanadmin to export/import

**export:**

```
svnadmin dump --quiet --revision 0:xxx /home/svn/repo1 > /tmp/repo1.dump
```

**import:**

```
svnadmin load --quiet /home/svn/repo2 < /tmp/repo1.dump
```

**OR use *move***

```
svn move https://svn.example.com/repo1/ https://svn.example.com/repo2/
```

Comment: The OP is not asking how to copy/move the repository itself, but how commit changes from the same working copy to a different repository.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do it with Xcode, but you can use the `svn` command to relocate the repository URL in your working copy:

```
svn switch --relocate <from URL> <to URL>
```

**NOTE**: always make a backup of your working copy before... ; )

About relocate:

> Rewrite working copy URL metadata to reflect a syntactic change only.
>   This is used when repository's root URL changes (such as a scheme or
>   hostname change) but your working copy still reflects the same
>   directory within the same repository.